# Save dictionary to json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've try to save the dictinary to json file by the following code snippet. 
I could not found this site's answer  for solving this.

What's wrong?

```
dic = { b'pejorative': 0, b'greek': 1, b'from': 2, b'english': 3, b'and': 4 ... } 
json.dump(dic, 
        open(os.path.join(path, 'model_dict.json'), 'wb'), 
        ensure_ascii=False))
```

or

```
json.dump(dic, open(os.path.join(path, 'model_dict.json'), 'wb'), 

error : 

* TypeError: key b'pejorative' is not a string* 
* TypeError: key b'as' is not a string
```

Comment: Why have you put a `b` in front of the keys. I don't think dictionaries support variables like that.

Comment: remove `b''` from your key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong ? Well, it's written in all letters in the error message:

> TypeError: key b'pejorative' is not a string

Your dict keys are bytestrings (cf the `b''` in front), `json.dump()` wants them to be (unicode) strings.

A workaround is to rebuilt the dict with unicode strings decoded from the bytestrings, ie:

```
dic = {key.decode():value for key, value in dic.items()}
```

but this may raise if any of your keys contains anything else than utf-8 (which is the default encoding for `bytes.decode()`).

The real solution is of course to fix the way you initially populate your
dict so you use unicode strings right from the start.

Comment: Why can't you build proper unicode objects from byte strings?

Comment: @allo that's what `key.decode()` is doing - but calling `bytestring.decode()` without a specified encoding only works when the bytestring either contains only ascii chars or is encoded in your interpreter's default encoding, so it's safer to fix the problem at the source using the "unicode sandwich" pattern (decode everything at input, encode everything at output, only use unicode internally).

Comment: I just think restricting the conversion to ascii isn't always an solution. If you know its an utf-8 bytestring convert it to unicode decoded from utf-8 and non-ascii chars are fine.

Comment: @allo I'm afraid I don't get your point here... If you _do_know how your bytestrings are encoded then _of course_ you can safely decode them passing the right encoding to `.decode()` - but that's exactly the point of the unicode sandwich pattern: decode everything at input (where you're likeley to know the encoding) so you don't have to worry about it anywhere else in your code.

Comment: I guess with your edit it's right. I just wondered, why you need to restrict yourself to ascii as input.

Comment: @allo it's not that you "need to restrict yourself" to whatever, it's that to _reliably_ decode a bytestring you _need_ to know it's encoding - unless your bystestring only contains ascii characters that is. Else you may either get a `UnicodeDecodeError` or, worse, some random crap.

Comment: So you ALWAYS need to know it's encoding, because you cannot assume it is only ascii chars as you cannot assume its utf-8 or its iso-8859-15 encoded. The other option is to go with the most likely encoding and tell the decode option how to handle errors (replace or ignore). And/Or let the user tell your program, what's the input encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The official document has clearly claimed

> The json module always produces str objects, not bytes objects. Therefore, fp.write() must support str imput

Actually, in python, strings are stored in memory as `str` objects which are `Unicode` encoded sequence, if you need you can use `.decode()`

Answer (score 0):

I have had just the same problem.  If you need to convert "multidimensional" dict to UTF:

```
def convert2utf( data):
    converted_object={}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if (not isinstance(value, dict)) and (not isinstance(value, list)):
            converted_object[key.decode()]=value.decode()
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            converted_object[key.decode()]=convert2utf(value)
        else:
            sub_list=[]
            for next_item in value:
                sub_list.append(convert2utf(next_item))
            converted_object[key.decode()]=sub_list
    return converted_object
```